# Importing DefinitelyTyped modules in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm familiar with the reference tag in typescript, but none of the definitely typed modules seem to really work natively in a browser and if I use the 'import' tag to make the intellisense work it generates extraneous code for creating modules (I assume for use with node.js?) therefore I get exceptions in the browser.

```
///<reference path='paper/paper.d.ts' />

//import paper = require('paper'); //This makes intellisense work

paper.setup(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("#my-canvas"));

var path = new paper.Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';

var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
path.moveTo(start);
path.lineTo(start.add([200, -50]));
paper.view.draw();
```

Here's the generated file that keeps a require statement ... which means nothing in the browser. Any idea how to not get this to happen?

```
"use strict";
///<reference path='paper/paper.d.ts' />
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); 
var paper = require("paper"); //Garbage that causes exceptions
paper.setup(document.getElementById("#my-canvas"));
var path = new paper.Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';
var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
path.moveTo(start);
path.lineTo(start.add([200, -50]));
paper.view.draw();
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UMD, aka `as namespace` trick:

```
// custom-typings/paper.d.ts
import * from 'paper'
export as namespace paper

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": {
    "custom-typings"
  }
}
```

Comment: setting it to UMD and using 'import * as paper from 'paper';' worked